# 'genie' programming language usage outside Puppy Linux

Tags: genie

I would like to try programming [genie](http://live.gnome.org/Genie), but I can't find neither source code for it nor any version control repository. Does anybody know where can it be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the sources are all in the `valagenie{parser,scanner,tokentype}.vala` files [at Gnome's git repo](http://git.gnome.org./browse/vala/tree/vala).

It makes sense that Genie's sources are in the `vala` tree because you have to use `valac` to compile Genie scripts.  Without actually examining the source, I'm presuming that Genie just gets translated to Vala.

Comment: Genie is really just an alternative syntax to Vala - so there is just a separate lexer and parser for Genie in the Vala compiler. (Translating Genie to Vala and then Vala to C would be silly.)

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 12.4 only type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install valac
```

After you could use some libreries like:

1) GTK+

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

2) Dynamic listes

```
$ sudo apt-get install gee-1.0
```

3) Programation IDE: There is Valide too, but doesnt in repositories.

```
$ sudo apt-get install geany
```

and more see in Valadoc.org

I you want to se some code: [www.manualgenie.blogspot.com](http://manualgenie.blogspot.com)

Comment: That's nice to know that somebody's also interested in this language. Muchas gracias!